# $_FILES sometimes empty when sending a file with php CURL

Tags: php, file, curl, post

This code has been used for several years to send a file from Server A to Server B and Server C with no problems. But since a week ago for some unknown reason I am getting $_FILES empty only when sending from Server A to Server B:

For example:

Send file from Server A to Server B: $_FILES array is empty on Server B, no file arrived. No errors in CURL and no errors on Server B, $_FILES is set but empty.

Send file from Server A to Server C: $_FILES includes one file and the file arrived successfully.

Send file from Server C to Server B: $_FILES includes one file and the file arrived successfully.

Send file from local PC to Server B and Server C: $_FILES includes one file and the file arrived successfully.

So the issue is only when sending from Server A to Server B (as already mentioned this used to work). In the firewall logs nothing unusual.

Have played with header options which made no difference; Server A php version is 7.4.1;

```
$ch = curl_init();
$cfile = curl_file_create(realpath($zipFile),'application/zip','export.zip');
$fileArray['export']=$cfile;
$headr = array();
$headr[] = 'Content-type:multipart/form-data';
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_URL, $listenerUrl);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER,$headr);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $fileArray);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, true);
//@@@@@@
#curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, TRUE);
#curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, TRUE);
//@@@@@@@
$result = curl_exec($ch);
```

Comment: Downgrading Server A (sending server) from php version 7.4.2 to 7.3.14 fixed the issue. Anyone know why $_Files is empty with the above code in 7.4.2 but works in 7.3.14?